# jQuery.slideDown completing instantly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I'm trying to do a simple slide out effect, then add a class with `display:none;`

But for some reason, the jQuery animation is completing instantly, instead of using the duration as the docs say.  I tried using different values, and 'slow' / 'fast'.
Looking at the source in Chrome's developer tools, the DOM is updated instantly.  Removing the callback doesn't make the animation work either,  it just does nothing in that case.

```
$('.type-panel').slideDown(500, function () {
    $(this).addClass('panel-hidden')
});

<div class="ed-panel type-panel">
    //bunch of stuff
</div>
```

What am I missing?

(I have jQuery and jQueryUI referenced)

Comment: What's the initial state of your `.type-panel` element? If the animation is not being animated then it means your element is already in the `slideDown`'s final state. Probably you meant to use `.slideUp()` instead

Comment: Ah,  me for genius.  slideDown = show it,  not hide it.  I knew it was something stupidly simple

Comment: Just adding up to Alexander: the addClass panel-hidden did not work, because after slideDown jQuery modifies the element style, which overrides any css rules.
Here is a sample fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZzErK/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you meant to use [`.slideUp()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/) to hide it.

```
$('.type-panel').slideUp(500, function() {
    $(this).addClass('panel-hidden');
});
```

Notice, `.slideUp()` will add automatically set the `display` to `none`.

Comment: Made no difference to mine, still remained instant. Starting to think my issue is CSS related to something Bourbon is adding.